# How do I type this TextMate Keyboard command?

Tags: keyboard, command, textmate, shortcut

I have a Ruby on Rails (RoR) document open and want to make the <%= %> pair of brackets. In TextMate, it's under Bundles > Ruby > Insert ERB's and the key command looks like:

```
^ >
```

How do I type that on a Mac? <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextMate document must be set to HTML (Rails), not Ruby on Rails.